# IOTA and LoraWAN: Proof of Concept of storing data in the Tangle

Tags: transaction, tangle, iota-network, internet-of-things, iota-cli

I found an article here :([**Link to the article**](https://medium.com/@harmvandenbrink/lorawan-and-iota-proof-of-concept-of-storing-data-in-real-time-in-the-tangle-9ba6a109b552)) entitled "**LoraWAN and IOTA: Proof of Concept of storing data in real time in the Tangle**" , written by *Harm van den Brink* ([**IOTA foundation member**](https://smartsystemssummit.com/speaker/harm-van-den-brink/)).

According to the article, the device that is used in the article is here: [**Link to the device**](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/TTGO-T-Deer-Pro-mini-LoRa-433MHz-868MHz-915MHz-Mega328-for-arduino/32948588389.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dSUGiJN).

The thing is not clear to me is a general view of the architecture of this approach. That is, is it possible to install IOTA on such small devices that supports LoRaWAN ?

In my opinion, the proposed idea in the article has an architecture like this figure:
[image]

In which, IOTA is installed on an ordinary (normal) computer (instead of installing on small and low power device introduced in the article ([**Link to the device**](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/TTGO-T-Deer-Pro-mini-LoRa-433MHz-868MHz-915MHz-Mega328-for-arduino/32948588389.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dSUGiJN)))

In more general question, is it possible to install IOTA on such a small device? Or as the above figure, we have to install IOTA on a normal computer which receives the messages from those devices and then encapsulates them in a IOTA transaction and sends the transaction to the IOTA tangle?

Comment: Don't have the time to answer in detail at the moment, but you can find some information about IOTA on IoT devices in our [paper](http://user.it.uu.se/~atiel485/iota-iot-2018.pdf) and [medium article](https://hackernoon.com/lessons-learned-from-evaluating-iota-on-internet-of-things-devices-a44575e606de).

Comment: @kfx , Could you just say your opinion about my figure on high level view of architecture of that article? [Link to the figure](https://imgur.com/a/ZvkgkBu) Do you agree? Thank you.

Comment: @kfx , My simple question is that if IOTA is installed and run on an ordinary computer (as shown in my figure: https://imgur.com/a/ZvkgkBu)? or on these small devices (TTGO T Deer Pro mini LoRa)?